# Express app.get given an array

Tags: javascript, express

I'm reading code from https://github.com/FrankHassanabad/Oauth2orizeRecipes which demonstrate the use of [OAuth2orize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize), which can be used to implement OAuth2 authorization server.

The question I'm asking is nothing fancy though. I just have trouble with the basics of Express 3.x.

In app.js:

```
oauth2 = require('./oauth2')
. . . 
app.get('/dialog/authorize', oauth2.authorization);
```

In Oauth2.js:

```
exports.authorization = [ 
    login.ensureLoggedIn(),
    server.authorization(function (clientID, redirectURI, scope, done) {
        db.clients.findByClientId(clientID, function (err, client) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }   
            if(client) {
                client.scope = scope;
            }   
            // WARNING: For security purposes, it is highly advisable to check that
            //          redirectURI provided by the client matches one registered with
            //          the server.  For simplicity, this example does not.  You have
            //          been warned.
            return done(null, client, redirectURI);
        }); 
    }), 
    function (req, res, next) {
        //Render the decision dialog if the client isn't a trusted client
        //TODO Make a mechanism so that if this isn't a trusted client, the user can recorded that they have consented
        //but also make a mechanism so that if the user revokes access to any of the clients then they will have to
        //re-consent.
        db.clients.findByClientId(req.query.client_id, function(err, client) {
            if(!err && client && client.trustedClient && client.trustedClient === true) {
                //This is how we short call the decision like the dialog below does
                server.decision({loadTransaction: false}, function(req, callback) {
                    callback(null, { allow: true }); 
                })(req, res, next);
            } else {
                res.render('dialog', { transactionID: req.oauth2.transactionID, user: req.user, client: req.oauth2.client }); 
            }
        });
    }   
];
```

So, is it because `app.get()` can take an array of middlewares? I'm trying to find where the code to app.get() is to figure out but I can't find it.

**EDIT:**
I'm on Express 3.6. So according to Infer-on's answer, correct me if I'm wrong.
You mean oauth2.authorization *array* instead of *module*?

app.VERB goes to `this._router[method].apply(this._router, arguments);`

where arguments is an array-like object with exactly one item, which is the `oauth2.authorization` array.

Then goes to router/index.js in the function defined by:

```
methods.forEach(function(method){
  Router.prototype[method] = function(path){
    var args = [method].concat([].slice.call(arguments));
    this.route.apply(this, args);
    return this;
  };  
});
```

Here, what previously was `arguments` is now `path`. And then becomes args. So the original array given by `oauth2.authorization` is still there and is an item inside `args` which has the length of 2, the first item is the method name "get" and the second is the array.

this.route is defined in the same file:

```
Router.prototype.route = function(method, path, callbacks){
  var method = method.toLowerCase()
    , callbacks = utils.flatten([].slice.call(arguments, 2));

  // ensure path was given
  if (!path) throw new Error('Router#' + method + '() requires a path');

  // ensure all callbacks are functions
  callbacks.forEach(function(fn){
    if ('function' == typeof fn) return;
    var type = {}.toString.call(fn);
    var msg = '.' + method + '() requires callback functions but got a ' + type;
    throw new Error(msg);
  }); 

  // create the route
  debug('defined %s %s', method, path);
  var route = new Route(method, path, callbacks, {
    sensitive: this.caseSensitive,
    strict: this.strict
  }); 

  // add it
  (this.map[method] = this.map[method] || []).push(route);
  return this;
};
```

Since there is `utils.flatten([].slice.call(arguments, 2));` the array from `oauth2.authorization` gets flattened. So it's as if the things sent weren't array but normal arguments. (I don't know what the "2" is doing). The 3rd of the `oauth2.authorization` is the callback that's easy to understand. The first is `login.ensureLoggedIn()` which is a middleware? The second is `server.authorization()`..but I'm not entirely sure what it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the `get` method, after the *first argument*, application will add the route, then will pass the other arguments to related controller

```
this._router[method].apply(this._router, arguments);
```

**app.js**

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
```

**index.js**

```
// controller
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

**application.js**

```
methods.forEach(function(method){
  app[method] = function(path){
    if ('get' == method && 1 == arguments.length) return this.set(path);

    // deprecated
    if (Array.isArray(path)) {
      console.trace('passing an array to app.VERB() is deprecated and will be removed in 4.0');
    }

    // if no router attached yet, attach the router
    if (!this._usedRouter) this.use(this.router);

    // setup route
    this._router[method].apply(this._router, arguments);
    return this;
  };
});
```

so

```
app.get('/dialog/authorize', oauth2.authorization);
```

for the `/dialog/authorize` *view* will be passed the `authorization` method exported by `oauth2.authorization` module

**EDIT**

I'm not sure of the array export, try something like [Implement Authorization Endpoint](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize):

```
app.get('/dialog/authorize',
  login.ensureLoggedIn(),
    server.authorization(function (clientID, redirectURI, scope, done) {
        db.clients.findByClientId(clientID, function (err, client) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }   
            if(client) {
                client.scope = scope;
            }   
            // WARNING: For security purposes, it is highly advisable to check that
            //          redirectURI provided by the client matches one registered with
            //          the server.  For simplicity, this example does not.  You have
            //          been warned.
            return done(null, client, redirectURI);
        }); 
    }), 
    function (req, res, next) {
        //Render the decision dialog if the client isn't a trusted client
        //TODO Make a mechanism so that if this isn't a trusted client, the user can recorded that they have consented
        //but also make a mechanism so that if the user revokes access to any of the clients then they will have to
        //re-consent.
        db.clients.findByClientId(req.query.client_id, function(err, client) {
            if(!err && client && client.trustedClient && client.trustedClient === true) {
                //This is how we short call the decision like the dialog below does
                server.decision({loadTransaction: false}, function(req, callback) {
                    callback(null, { allow: true }); 
                })(req, res, next);
            } else {
                res.render('dialog', { transactionID: req.oauth2.transactionID, user: req.user, client: req.oauth2.client }); 
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You mean oauth2.authorization array instead of module? Could you check my edit?

Comment: @huggie have you tried to directly pass arguments instead of export the array?

Comment: It's actually not my code. It's a working code from Oauth2orizeRecipes and I'm trying to understand how it works.

Comment: I see. It's doing something very similar to what's written in the `oauth2orize` documentation. It must be the same thing with or without the array. Now I just have to understand what that's doing, and that would be another question. Thank you very much for your help I appreciated it.